# Git - How to return to the last commit and delete all files not commited?

Tags: git

I need to return to the last commit state. I've done a Git Reset Hard, but when I make new changes to the code and try to commit, I see that all the files tahs I don't wan't to have in the repo are there.

How can I make a Reset that also delete the not commited files?

Best Regards,

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903953/git-revert-last-commit-and-remove-it-from-history

Answer (score 5):

`git reset --hard` will put you back to the last commit, losing any changes you have made to files that have already been committed.

`git clean -xdf` will then remove any files and directories that you have created but have not yet committed to git.

Running both of these should put you back into a clean state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It is not working, the files are there. any other clues? Best Regards,

Comment: what is the output of `git clean -f` and `git status`?

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout -- .` (there is a dot at the end of command) will revert all changes in working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove files that aren't being tracked then try the following:

```
git add .
git reset --hard
```

I think there's a more appropriate way, but can't think of it right now. Will post it if I do.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you have:

- `git clean -x`: removes files not under version control, including ignored files
- `git reset --hard`: goes to the mentioned commmit, checks out the files just as they are recorded in it

Using both should give you what you want, if not, it's a bug.